# Send Ctrl+P through serial with JSSC

Tags: java, serial-port, keyevent

Im working on a program for work. The program is just a terminal for connecting to devices via serial and in this specific device, it requires you to press Ctrl and P simultaneously to enter a menu. At the moment, my temporary solution is to use JSwing's Robot, which is exactly what i DONT want to do.

i thought if i sent `SerialPort.writeInt(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL + KeyEvent.VK_P);` it would perhaps do the trick. I tried writing `KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL` and `KeyEvent.VK_P` in their own line but they are sent individually, not together to simulate a "Control-Down->P".

Does anyone know of a possible alternative that isnt Robot? maybe there is a workaround?

Comment: Isn't `SerialPort.writeInt(16);` sufficient?  (Control-P, in ascii, has a value of 16).

Comment: Oops. `KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL & KeyEvent.VK_P`, which is 16.

Comment: @JohnHascall That should be an answer as it solves the OP's problem.  Actually ElliotFrisch's comment does as well :-)

Comment: Ok @JimGarrison , I made an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL is 17
KeyEvent.VK_P is 80

17 + 80 = 97 => not good
17 & 80 = 16 => control-P
```

So:

```
SerialPort.writeInt(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL & KeyEvent.VK_P);
  or
SerialPort.writeInt(16);
```

Comment: wow, i didnt know you could do that. i cant try it now but i will definitely give it a try. thanks!